# Padding: EdgeInserts | Not moving widget?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to position text to be closer to the left edge, than to the centre.

Upon research using flutter, it appears that the correct way to do so is using `const EdgeInserts`

However, when using const edge inserts, the text on my page only changes position by a minuscule amount, which is barely noticeable. Am I doing something wrong with the code below?

```
Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, bottom: 50),
                child: Text(
                  'Some Text',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
```

Here is a sample of what is happening, vs what I want

[image]

Edit for answer:

```
class Onboarding1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            "assets/Onboarding1_Photo.png",
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, bottom: 50),
                child: Text(
                  'Some Text',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stretch view, you can add to `Column`:

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
```

Full example with two texts with different paddings and alignment:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 300,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 10,
                top: 30,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Some Text',
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24,
                  fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                right: 50,
                top: 30,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Some Text',
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24,
                  fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solution with two nested `Columns` using `CrossAxisAlignment.start` on both and a `Padding` on the inner `Column`.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(
              'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/de/Colosseo_2020.jpg/2560px-Colosseo_2020.jpg'),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Some Text',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                Text('This is some text. This is some text.'),
                const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                OutlineButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('Continue'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add crossAxisAlignment on Column widget to start left.

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, bottom: 50),
      child: Text(""),
    )
  ],
)
```

Comment: This did not adjust the positioning at all. Any thoughts?

Comment: @KyleUSA Can you check what is the parent widget on Column().. You might have another column above maybe?

Comment: Yes, I have another column above. I have edited the post for your reference. Would this affect it?